# Specifying char array size in extern statement for sizeof command

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010

There was

```
char B[200];
```

in the static library.  It was referred as

```
extern char B[];  // (1)
```

in the header that is included in the client's code. 
Once I needed to use `sizeof(B)` compiler complained and changing to

```
extern char B[200]; // (2)
```

calmed compiler down.

Library and client code are c++, but it uses C linkage (header's extern declarations surrounded by

```
extern "C" { ... }
```

Is there any potential problem if I use (2) instead of (1)?

**P.S.** I put 200 for simplicity. it is a constant defined in the header file that comes with the library.

library header:

```
#define MAXLEN 200
```

Actually even if it is not a library, but in a separate file(compilation unit) the problem is similar.

**Is there any way that (1) could've used in this big old code that I might break by using (2)?**

Answer (score 9):

If the library implementation ever changes the size of `B` you'll have a mismatch and possibly a variety of bugs to hunt down. The library writer should provide a constant that describes the size of the array. As noted in a comment the library writer could easily provide this via a constant or function written in terms of `sizeof(b)` to make it very resilient to changes in the library.

Comment: Indeed, the library should define `const size_t BSIZE = sizeof(B);` and `extern const size_t BSIZE;` in its header, or perhaps use a function to return the size (the function approach works better with shared libraries and position-independent code).

Comment: providing BSIZE is a good advice. Thanks.  But I put 200 for simplicity. There is a constant `MAXLEN`, and it is `#define`-ed in the header that comes with library, so it will always be the same.  Is there any way that (1) could've used in this big old code that I might break by using (2)?

Comment: Use then `extern char B[MAXLEN]; // (2)` instead, so you avoid the potential size mismatch.

Comment: I have to use (2) and I will use it. It doesn't compile with (1).  The question is what potentially can it break, since it is very big and old code.

Comment: you should use a more accurate and specific name for the macro, or someone might use this macro who already has a macro called "MAXLEN"  in use, because MAXLEN is much to generic... (as is macs `check()` macro..*GRRR*) rather use "MYLIB_MAXLEN" or "B_ARRAY_LEN" or something similar

Comment: This is why the library should include the public header in its own implementation files - the compiler would then error on a mismatch.

Comment: @Seyran: Your change should not break anything - the complete definition of `B` can simply be used in places where the old incomplete definition could not. It will not return different results anywhere that the old `B` could be used.